# Error function representation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, error-function

Can someone help about proving the following relationship:

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{erfc}\left(\sqrt a\right) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-a} \times  \frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt \pi} \times \frac{\operatorname{erf}\left(\sqrt y\right)}{ \left(a + y\right)^{2}} \,dy
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

Just use the identity
$$
\frac{1}{(a+y)^2}=\int_0^\infty d\xi\ \xi e^{-\xi (a+y)}
$$
to rewrite the r.h.s. as
$$
e^{-a}\sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}}\int_0^\infty d\xi\ \xi\ e^{-a\xi} \int_0^\infty dy\ \mathrm{erf}(\sqrt{y})e^{-\xi y}\ .
$$
The $y$-integral admits an explicit antiderivative
$$
\int dy\ \mathrm{erf}(\sqrt{y})e^{-\xi y}=\frac{\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\xi +1} \sqrt{y}\right)}{\xi  \sqrt{\xi +1}}-\frac{\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{y}\right) e^{-\xi y}}{\xi }+C\ ,
$$
as one can verify by differentiation. Therefore, the definite integral reads
$$
\int_0^\infty dy\ \mathrm{erf}(\sqrt{y})e^{-\xi y}=\frac{1}{\xi  \sqrt{\xi +1}}\ ,
$$
so that the r.h.s. is effectively equal to
$$
e^{-a}\sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}}\int_0^\infty d\xi\frac{e^{-a \xi}}{\sqrt{\xi+1}}\ ,
$$
whose antiderivative is also known
$$
\int d\xi\frac{e^{-a \xi}}{\sqrt{\xi+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^a \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{a} \sqrt{\xi +1}\right)}{\sqrt{a}}+C_1.
$$
Using the known asymptotics $\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{a} \sqrt{\xi +1}\right)\to 1$ for $\xi\to\infty$, the claimed equality with $\text{erfc}(\sqrt{a})=1-\text{erf}(\sqrt{a})$ is readily established.